# ubuntu infected by something from windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, malware, virus

when sharing some files with one of my friends who uses windows, i found a suspicious file in his pen-drive, deleted from it, but after that my trash can shows its full, deleted everything , but its still shows the same, transferred important files to my external hdd, reinstalled OS, the problem was gone, but when i put them back in, the same thing happened, now its driving me crazy... a few years back, i faced the same problem, but back then my external-hDD was in ntfs, and what the result was, after a while i found a chunk of bad sectors in it... and later it crashed... so now i'm a bit worried

Comment: Well a piece of software you deleted isn't going to cause bad sectors on your HDD, so that is not the issue, unless this hard drive is going bad as well. However, I doubt that is the issue, and it seems like it has something to do with the filesystems.

Comment: may be... but honestly my computer is behaving lil strange... suddenly it went to text console mood, when plugged my phone to it, quit responding in anyway, had to shut it down, then its gone :@
but thanks a lot, for helping :D

Comment: Its not possible for a Windows malicious file to infect a Linux system.

Comment: @Ramhound It is possible that the Linux malicious file was downloaded from Windows and was benign until moved to Linux.

Comment: @ekaj - Very unlikely considering it would have required sudo permissions.  The first also was using Windows from the sound of it so any attacks targeted against that user would have been Windows based.  Furthermore its normally Windows files transferred from Linux that infected Windows not the other way around.

Comment: @Ramhound You can download a Linux file either way, he didn't say how the file was obtained other than through a flash drive. I've downloaded Linux packages a few times on Windows and transferred to a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

The binary of Windows is different from Linux and thus it's impossible to have a malicious Windows software that can affect Linux.

To solve your problem you can secure delete(which is likely as wiping) your pendrive.

Install the package

```
 sudo apt-get install secure-delete
```

This has four command:

> srm - securely delete an existing file 
>   smem - securely delete traces of a file from ram 
>   sfill - wipe all the space marked as empty on your 
>   hard drive sswap - wipe all the data from you swap space.

Now to clean your pendrive

```
sudo srm /path-to-mounting-point-of-your-pen-drive
```

NOTE: this will delete every thing in your pendrive.